# Oracle query to get latest table or stored procedure schema change?

Tags: oracle, schema

I'm trying to write a query to get the latest schema changes to a table or stored procedure on Oracle.

This is how to do this on Sybase:

```
select top 10 name from sysobjects where type = 'U' order by crdate desc
```

(I accept that this is built on created date and not modified date - I'd appreciate anyone who can show me how the modified date works in Sybase for tables but what I'm looking for is Oracle schema change date right now).

My question is: What is the **Oracle query to get latest table or stored procedure schema change?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be specific about the table or procedure, you can limit like below

with **11g database**

```
select * from
(SELECT * FROM user_objects where OBJECT_TYPE in ('TABLE','PROCEDURE') ORDER BY last_ddl_time DESC)
where rownum <= 10;
```

The above will give the latest changed objects either in table or procedure.

whereas in **12c database** no need to use subquery

```
SELECT * FROM user_objects 
  where OBJECT_TYPE in ('TABLE','PROCEDURE') 
    ORDER BY last_ddl_time DESC
      FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from
(SELECT * FROM user_objects ORDER BY last_ddl_time DESC)
where rownum <= 10;
```

`user_objects` contains all the objects owned by the current user (= current schema objects)

`all_objects` contains all the objects on which the user has any privileges

`dba_objects` contains all the DB objects (requires some special privileges to access).

all_ and dba_ have the additional column `owner`

#### 3rd party edit

You may want to read [does-rebuilding-an-index-update-the-last-ddl-time ...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206044/does-rebuilding-an-index-update-the-last-ddl-time-attribute-in-all-objects-dba-o)

From [ROWNUM Pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255)

> For each row returned by a query, the ROWNUM pseudocolumn returns a
>   number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a
>   table or set of joined rows. The first row selected has a ROWNUM of 1,
>   the second has 2, and so on.
>
> You can use ROWNUM to limit the number of rows returned by a query,...